# sql CASE STATEMENT WITH DATE CRITERIA

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write to script using a CASE statemetn that compares two dates.  For instance, if a patient cancels an appointment after the appointment date, it should read 'after';  if patient cancels prior to the appointment date, it should read 'before'.   How can I accomplish this?

Example (The below didn't work):

```
Select 
   PatientName, PatientFirstName, PatientLastName, PatientSSN, Age, Gender, 
   AppointmentDateTime, CancelDateTime, CancelNoShowCode, Appointment_Status, 
   CancellationReason, CancellationRemarks, LocationName, InstitutionName, 
   DivisionName, AppointmentSID, 
   CASE WHEN CancelDateTime > 'AppointmentDateTime' then 'after'
    WHEN CancelDateTime < 'AppointmentDateTime' then 'BEFORE'
    END as WHENCANCELLED
from #mhvisits2  
where CancelDateTime is NOT null
order by PatientName
```

Comment: Do you have a column named `AppointmentDateTime`?, if so, then all you need for your query to work is to remove the single quotes (`'`) from `'AppointmentDateTime'`

Answer (score 0):

Select 
   PatientName, PatientFirstName, PatientLastName, PatientSSN, Age, Gender, 
   AppointmentDateTime, CancelDateTime, CancelNoShowCode, Appointment_Status, 
   CancellationReason, CancellationRemarks, LocationName, InstitutionName, 
   DivisionName, AppointmentSID, 
   
CASE 

WHEN CancelDateTime > AppointmentDateTime then 'after' 
    WHEN CancelDateTime < AppointmentDateTime then 'BEFORE'
    ELSE ''
END as WHENCANCELLED

from #mhvisits2
where CancelDateTime is NOT null
order by PatientName

You are missing ELSE condition in your CASE statement and remove any (') from your column names.